# When I mouse over this bootstrap btn-info it looses its background colour

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why when I mouse over this button:

[image]

Does it loose its background colour :/

[image]

The code for the button is :

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <%= link_to "ClassWeb", "/" ,:class=>"navbar-brand"  %>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li style=""><%= link_to "My Events", current_user %></li>
            <li style=""><%= link_to "New Event", new_event_url %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">My Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><%= link_to "My page", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path , method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><%= link_to "Create Event", new_event_url, class: "btn btn-info" ,role: "button" %> </li>    
      </ul>

      <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
   </div>
</nav>
```

The styles applied to the ul and li and anchor elements is found below - I have scanned this a number of times and failed to find the reason for this behaviour(apologies for the CSS markup -I copied the applied styles from Google Chrome's inspector tool and its slightly oddly formatted and potentially not all entirely valid:

```
element.style {
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #777;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

a:visited {
  color: #666;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
a, a:visited {
  color: #369ec1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
localhost/media="all"
.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
}
localhost/media="all"
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
localhost/media="all"
a {
  color: #000;
}
localhost/media="all"
a {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}
localhost/media="all"
a {
  background: transparent;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
a, a:visited {
  color: #369ec1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
localhost/media="all"
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: auto;
}
Inherited from li
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, li, ol, p, td, th, ul {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
user agent stylesheetli {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
Inherited from ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
localhost/media="all"
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
localhost/media="all"
p, ol, ul, td {
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, li, ol, p, td, th, ul {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
ul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
user agent stylesheetul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from body
localhost/media="all"
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
localhost/media="all"
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
localhost/media="all"
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, li, ol, p, td, th, ul {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
Inherited from html
localhost/media="all"
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
localhost/media="all"
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
localhost/media="all"
*:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
localhost/media="all"
*:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any ideas or advice would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Bootstrap has styles for hover `.nav>li>a:hover` where it sets`background-color: #eee`. You can add styles and overwrite it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvn3s0e/)

Comment: Is it on mouseover or click? Because I can't recreate this issue...

Comment: Its on mouseover - and I have tested this only happens when its within an <li> element inside a nav .... if i make the link somewhrre else it all works correctly...

Comment: I added the complete menu html to the original post to help you see - its the navbar-right element which is the Create Event background element with the problem

Comment: From what I can see you have an error in your HTML. Happens a lot when you just copy & paste code. The </ul> under the Login, new_user_session_path only closes (from what I can see) but I do not see the correct opening of the <ul>. You might want to format your HTML a little more an take care of indentation.

Comment: I have double checked the HTML and it looks fine to me? the </ul> is inside the else statement which shuts the original <ul> if the user is not logged in.

Comment: is it because the second <ul> declares another nav bar maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the browser, to style the element in the same way, when the element is hovered over.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
a, a:visited,
a:hover      // ... same styling when you :hover over it
 {
  color: #369ec1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

you're welcome.

Comment: I am not sure that should be needed - Check this : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options and specifically this example : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_button_elements&stacked=h as you can see the hover is working fine here...but not on my site...

Answer (score 0):

Well I eventually fixed it.

I used the following :

```
<ul class="navbar-right noBullets">
     <li><%= link_to "Create Event", new_event_url, class: "btn btn-info fixNavSlightIndent size11Text" ,role: "button" %> </li>
```

A couple of extra css styles to remove some of the stuff like bullet points and some of the vertical alignment problems but that fixed it. Probably a hack but I am happy!

Answer (score -1):

I dont see anyplace where you have declared the hover state for this button. So it will take the default from bootstrap. You should declare thse in your own css file for overrides and target the nav specifically.

```
.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Comment: Why is the default from bootstrap to remove all the colour?!

Comment: Its possible its the same as the BG color of your page. Bootstrap doesnt remove the BG color. 

You need to specifically set the hover if you want to set/keep a specific color. You havent supplied one in your css, or you havent given us all your css/mark up.

In the future, over ride the bootstrap class. Dont add more classes to it